# Ansible changed the fact value during union operation

Tags: ansible

I want to add a new object to the Ansible list, so I created code that looks like this:

```
- debug:
   msg: "{{distinguished_name_with_env }}"

- debug:
   msg: "{{_current_topics_operations }}"

# Add operations to global Ansible variable
- name: Add principal operations to global ACL topic list
  set_fact:
    _current_topics_operations: "{{ _current_topics_operations | union([ { 'distinguished_name': distinguished_name_with_env , 'operations':  item, 'topic_name':  topic_name  }]) }}"
  loop: "{{_topic_operations}}"
  run_once: True
```

and there is an output:

```
TASK [confluent.acl : debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 16 August 2021  16:02:56 +0200 (0:00:00.061)       0:00:18.834 ********* 
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: user_1-dev
ASK [confluent.acl : debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 16 August 2021  16:02:56 +0200 (0:00:00.067)       0:00:18.902 ********* 
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:[]
TASK [confluent.acl : to add  gldownload_topic_1] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 16 August 2021  16:02:57 +0200 (0:00:00.057)       0:00:19.412 ********* 
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - distinguished_name: write-dev
    operations: write
    topic_name: download_topic_1
  - distinguished_name: describe-dev
    operations: describe
    topic_name: download_topic_1
```

The problem occurs when a new object is added to the list. The value of Distinguished_name is different from before the union operation was performed

Before executing union operation:

```
distinguished_name_with_env  -> user_1-dev
```

During union operation:

```
distinguished_name_with_env -> describe-dev
distinguished_name_with_env -> write-dev
```

'Describe' and 'write' are store in _topic_operations list.

What should I do to get the correct value of a variable?

Comment: Inside your `set_fact` task you're never referring to the `distinguished_name_with_env` variable.

Comment: yes, I made a mistake in my question. I have changed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    distinguished_name_with_env: user_1-dev
    topic_name: download_topic_1
    _topic_operations:
      - describe-dev
      - write-dev

  tasks:

    # Add operations to global Ansible variable
    - name: Add principal operations to global ACL topic list
      set_fact:
        _current_topics_operations: "{{ _current_topics_operations
                                        | default([])
                                        | union( [ {'distinguished_name': distinguished_name_with_env ,
                                                    'operations': item,
                                                    'topic_name': topic_name } ]) }}"
      loop: "{{ _topic_operations }}"
      run_once: True

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _current_topics_operations }}"
```

and the output:

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************

TASK [Add principal operations to global ACL topic list] *****************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=describe-dev)
ok: [localhost] => (item=write-dev)

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "distinguished_name": "user_1-dev",
            "operations": "describe-dev",
            "topic_name": "download_topic_1"
        },
        {
            "distinguished_name": "user_1-dev",
            "operations": "write-dev",
            "topic_name": "download_topic_1"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************
```

if I have not understood it well, please clarify